# There are two elections in the community bulletin

Tags: bug, election

It's probably related to the fact that that there were two messages posted about it in the meta. Could this be fixed?

Comment: Most likely - interesting that both messages' links include `?cb=1` ("Community Bulletin #1"?) - looks like something for SE employees to investigate.

Answer (score 2):

One is an event, one is a post on Meta. So basically although it looks like a dupe it's actually two different things that coincidentally have the same title.

Comment: Yesterday it was two events, though. Someone must have changed it.

Comment: @Christofian - I didn't catch that, though I did see your post here yesterday. It seems to be resolved now though.